# FPGA Timing issue between Sys_CLock and Signal-Tap

Tags: fpga, timing, intel-fpga

When using SignalTap I do get a timing violation with a negative slack, between the System-Clock (FPGA_CLK1) via the internal ADC and the SignalTap signals. Here some screenshots:

**TimeQuest**
[image: TimeQuest]
**ChipPlanner**
[image]
**TechnologyMap**
[image]

If SignalTap is not included to the design, no timing issues at all. How to avoid such timing violation when using SignalTap in the same design and/or is there another issue for example with the FPGA_CLK1?
Thanks in advance for some hints..!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, is to register the signals you are trying to capture.  So basically, you are capturing one clock later than the "real" signal.  But if you register all the signals being monitored, then you should get better timing because those registers will be closer to the signal tap blob.

Also do it without a reset to take that timing element out of the equation.

```
always @ (posedge clk)
begin 
   sig1_out <= sig1_in;
   sig2_out <= sig2_in;
   sig3_out <= sig3_in;
   ....
   sigX_out <= sigX_in;
end
```

Hope that helps.